# why cant change visibilty using jquery /css/js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Code:

```
<div><button id="Button1" runat="server" onclick="showTable()"  style="float:right">Edit</button></div>
<table style="visibility:hidden" id="Table">
    <tr>       
        <td><buttonid="upDateBtn"runat="server"onclick="saveInfo()"style="float:left">UpDate</button></td>    
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
                <label visible="false">Head Line</label>
            </td></tr>  
</table>
```

When `button1` is clicked the table needs to be visible.
I have tried the following solutions:

1. `document.getElementById("#Table").style.visibility = "visible";`
2. `$("#Table").css("visibility","visible");`
3. create a class in `css` and select the table by class using jQuery.

Nothing worked as intended. 
Am I missing something?
Are there any other solutions maybe?

Comment: are you sure the `#Table` element is available when the script is executed

Comment: Try `alert($("#Table").length)` before it... also check whether there is any error in the conwole

Comment: I used the alert - inside document.ready function and it poped with no errors..

Comment: what was the alert message

Comment: zero but no exceptions

Comment: what is the problem... the element you are looking for is created after dom ready event...

Comment: how is this markup loaded? is it loaded via an ajax call like `load()` or created using a script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i saw you using `runat=server`  so I figured you are using .NET 
so your button code should be:

```
  <input type="button" value"Edit" id="button1" style="float:right"/>
```

instead of:

```
  <button id="Button1" runat="server" onclick="showTable()"  style="float:right">Edit</button>
```

and add to the javscript:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#Button1').click( function(){
                        showTable();
             });
   });
```

Comment: good question, but you need to change it to `display:none` and then use `$("#button1").show()`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.getElementById("Table").style.visibility = "visible";
```

You have used `"#Table"`, which is jQuery selector

jQuery Way

```
$("#Table").css('visibility','visible');
```

Comment: @user2560521, You have use `"#Table"`. I suggesting you to use `"Table"`. Just curious Is there multiple table with same Id?

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways to do what you want like:

change your html into this:

```
<button id="Button1" runat="server"   style="float:right">Edit</button>
<table style="display:none" id="Table">
<tr>       
           <td><buttonid="upDateBtn"runat="server"onclick="saveInfo()"style="float:left">UpDate</button></td>    
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
        <label visible="false">Head Line</label>
        </td></tr>  
</table>
```

and jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Button1').click(function(){
        $("#Table").show(); 
    });
});
```

Another way is to use class.
add this to your css

```
.table-visible{
    display:visible;
}
.table-not-visible{
    display:none;
}
```

your html like:

```
<button id="Button1" runat="server"   style="float:right">Edit</button>
<table class="table-not-visible" id="Table">
<tr>       
           <td><buttonid="upDateBtn"runat="server"onclick="saveInfo()"style="float:left">UpDate</button></td>    
    </tr>
    <tr><td>
        <label visible="false">Head Line</label>
        </td></tr>  
</table>
```

and jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#Button1').click(function(){
            $("#Table").removeClass('table-not-visible').addClass('table-visible');  //or use toggle
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

U can do this easily by jquery

```
$("#Table").hide();
$("#button1").click(function()
{
$("#Table").show();
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: i tried it but it hides the table when the button is clicked.. do i need to delete the visibility property from the table? when page is load i need the table to be invisible, only after click the table need to be visible

Comment: Yes! Remove this style="visibility:hidden" from table .Onload it will hide the table with above code

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$("#Table").css('visibility','visible');
```

Edit:

You have correct code for hiding the table. It is pretty possible that the code is unreachable. You need to ensure that whatever handlers you have used, should be initiated on document ready. Try giving alert just before the code you are using to hide.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("Table").style.visibility = "visible"; //or
$("#Table").css("visibility","visible");//or
$("#Table").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

change style property as style="display:none" and then u can use css('visibility','visible)

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VmMX8/

```
$(document).ready(function()
              {
                  $("#Table").css('visibility','visible');
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try any of these provided u load jQuery library:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#Button1').live('click', function(){
         $("#Table").show(); //this
         $("#Table").css('display','block'); //or this
         $("#Table").css('visibility','visible'); //or this
    });
});
```

Or with pure Javascript:

```
function showTable(){
    document.getElementById("Table").style.display= "block";
}
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExFW5/4/)

Comment: Make sure you are loading jquery..library
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>